# IOS Model View Controller communication for live update from sliders in popover

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uislider

I have an iPad app that consists of a main view and associated view controller which draws some fancy graphics. The things that are drawn are controlled by a host of parameters (mostly floats) which at the moment I store in the main view controller class. The main view asks for the parameters inside of drawRect.

I would like to live-update the main view from a slider inside of a popover menu. However the popover contains a UINavigationController which contains a UITableViewController which contains custom UITableViewCells which contain the sliders so getting the message back associating the right controls to the right data variables is a pain. Also the messages have to go both ways because I have to initialize the slider positions using the data when they first appear.

My main question is therefore what is the elegant way to send the slider change information back to the main view controller and to have it live-update the main view. I realize that I should be using delegates but since I have maybe 30 parameters I could end up writing a lot of selectors and I'm not sure how I should be propagating the information about the main delegate target up through the view controller stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not do this with NSNotifications.

Instead I would simply create custom view controllers for every controller in the hierarchy down to the final UITableViewController which each take a reference to the main view controller. Like that they can both get and set the properties directly.

Note that I would not, however, pass the reference to main controller to the UITableViewCells themselves, but handle any setting and getting of properties in the table view, but this might be a matter of style.

Comment: I decided to use this technique because actually my code turns out to be not too bad for this approach once the parameters are stored in NSDictionary.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say without knowing more about your overall structure, but I would probably us an NSNotification to do this. You can get to anywhere from anywhere with a notification, and you can pass an NSDictionary in the userInfo, which can contain as many floats (converted to NSNumbers) as you want.

Comment: Hmm that looks pretty interesting, I will take a look at NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: It was very useful to suggest using a NSDictionary to hold the parameters. I now get and set the parameters by name. This allows me to avoid having getters and setters for every parameter, there is just a single one that takes an NSDictionary as arguments.

Comment: I chose not to actually use the notification center, even though it looks useful, because it does not easily allow the initialization of the slider values from the parameters since that has to pull data from the main view controller. It turns out that using delegates and NSDictionary properties was sufficiently clean.